# ViewHolder views flash/blink OnBind

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

**Issue**

Every time I call the OnBind() method inside my holders, views within them will flash or blink or maybe even fade.

I'm just pretty lost as to why, I've tried a number of things.

1. Changing them to have null as a background or have them all be a solid color.
2. Making sure nothing is gone at any point.
3. Removed any animations.
4. Asked Google a thousand times, a thousand ways.
5. Searched on here.

**Thoughts**

I've always thought that I would have to eventually try and hide it with animations and styling. Seeing it as just a side effect of the binding.

This is part of a larger project, obviously. So I still have to do all the animations, that's why I haven't done it for this yet. Figured I'd just ask and see if anyone could help find the solution another way in the meantime.

Any help, tips or advice would be great. Hopefully the code links work and are build able for everyone.

Thanks,
Jon.

**Code**

I'm not sure how much code I need to add in here, so I'll go small at first. If more should be added please let me know and I will. However I put it all on Github and Dropbox(Example Apk & Zip).
Links are at the bottom.

*HeaderHolder.java*

```
public class HeaderHolder extends BaseHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.header_title_text)
    TextView _titleTextView;
    @Bind(R.id.header_status_image)
    ImageView _statusImageView;
    @BindDrawable(R.drawable.ic_selected)
    Drawable _statusSelected;
    @BindDrawable(R.drawable.ic_non_selected)
    Drawable _statusNonselected;

    private Header _header;

    public HeaderHolder(View root, HolderCallBacks callbacks) {
        super(null, root, callbacks);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnBind(Base model) {
        this._header = (Header) model;
        String n = model._name();
        this._titleTextView.setText(n);
        this._statusImageView.setImageDrawable(this._header._iconset()._selected()
            ? this._statusSelected : this._statusNonselected);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.header_item_wrapper)
    public void _headerClick(View view) {
        this._callbacks.OnHolderClick(view, this._header);
    }
}
```

*IconsetHolder.java*

```
public class IconsetHolder extends BaseHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.iconset_icon_recycler)
    RecyclerView _iconsRecycler;

    private AdapterCallBacks _adapterCallbacks;

    public IconsetHolder(Context context, View root, AdapterCallBacks callbacks) {
        super(context, root, null);
        this._adapterCallbacks = callbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void OnBind(Base model) {
        Iconset i = (Iconset) model;
        this._iconsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(
                this._context, i._span(), GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        this._iconsRecycler.setAdapter(new ModelsAdapter(i._icons(), this._adapterCallbacks));
    }
}
```

*item_header.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/header_item_wrapper"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="56dip"
android:background="#595959"
tools:context=".views.adapters.holders.HeaderHolder">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="#fff8f8f8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="ICONSET"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_status_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*item_iconset.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/iconset_item_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@null"
tools:context=".views.adapters.holders.IconsetHolder">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/iconset_icon_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="#595959"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Example Links Removed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecyclerView` has some built in animations to it, using the [DefaultItemAnimator](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator.html). Specifically when you call `notifiyItemChanged()` it does a fade animation for the changing of the data in the `ViewHolder`. If you would like to disable this you can use the following:

```
RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = recyclerView.getItemAnimator(); // your recycler view here
if (animator instanceof DefaultItemAnimator) {
    ((DefaultItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
}
```

This will disable the item changed animation (the fade you are seeing).

Comment: Thank you so much! @Alex Townsend. Worked like a charm. Always hoped it would be an easy fix. Now the excessively over informed question seems pointless lol. Thanks again.